# How to run distributed shell application given in Hadoop 0.23.0 source example

Tags: java, hadoop

I found a distributed shell application in hadoop 0.23.0 source codes, Can any one please help me in running it. How to convert the application into a jar file by compiling the Client.java and applicationmaster.java with the  inclusion of required jar files. It will be a great help if some one help me in this issue or some source where i can learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use maven for that to build the whole Hadoop 0.23.x sources and you can pick up the jar in the project directory.

You can find more information about building and stuff here: 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Answer (score 7):

hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell.jar
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.applications.distributedshell.Client --jar /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell.jar --shell_command date --num_containers 1